# Restrict access to a WPF view based on AD group membership

Tags: c#, wpf, security, active-directory, active-directory-group

We have a WPF application. We would like to resrict access to the application based on the users AD group membership.

Could we do this as an attribute on each view, or as a check when the user starts the application?

Any code example would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Querying the AD? Restricting access to a view based on a certain criteria?

Comment: I want to check if the user is a member of group X, if he is not a member I want to block him. Maybe I simply have to query AD, or maybe there is a more elegant solution with some attribute I can put on the view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this on .NET 3.5 and up would be to use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// get your group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// check if current user is member of that group
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

if(user.IsMemberOf(group))
{
   // do something here....     
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!